# Activating Issue with Terminal Server in Windows Server 2012 R2 from Action Pack

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-server, rds, licensing

Installed a Server 2012 R2 Standard license with terminal services role from an Action Pack subscription. There are also 5 RDS CALs for this server available. Unfortunately I can't find any product keys to activate the terminal services. Microsoft only offers the following IMG file if I try to "download" the RDS CALs: SW_DVD5_NTRL_Windows_Svrs_2012_English_FPP_OEM_Std_DC_X18-32720_RDS.IMG

I previously installed the following Action Pack ISO for the Terminal Server: SW_DVD9_NTRL_Windows_Svrs_2012_R2_German_2_FPP_OEM_Std_DC_X19-82436.ISO

Do you know a further way to activate the license server without buying nor re-installing the complete server?

Answer (score 0):

After going to bed, the system has activated the terminal services role by itself. All components have been correctly licensed.